# Why UI changes are not instant in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a Qt app with simple UI - one button.

When the button is clicked, its slot is called, which sets button style to disabled and then starts background thread.

```
void MyApp::buttonClicked()
{
    theOnlyButton->setDisabled(true);

    QThread *workerThread;
    UploadWorker *worker;

    if (uploadInProgress) {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "Another upload is already running!");
        return;
    }

    workerThread = new QThread;

    worker       = new UploadWorker(QString("filename"));

    worker->moveToThread(workerThread);

    connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(doWork()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished(QString, QString)), workerThread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished(QString, QString)), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    // this takes care automatically of freeing memory
    connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), workerThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished(QString, QString)), this, SLOT(onUploadFinished(QString, QString)));

    workerThread->start();

    uploadInProgress = true;

}
```

The details of the function are irrelevant to my question - I set up breakpoint on every line and monitor main window when button becomes disabled. Interestingly, it does not happen after the `theOnlyButton->setDisabled(true);` call, not even in the next few lines. It actually lets function finish first and THEN it shows as disabled. The result is, that the button does not seem to be disabled instantly, but rather after little less than one second. Why? How to make this instant?

Comment: "The details of the function are irrelevant to my question..." Then why are you including them? Edit your code down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *the button does not seem to be disabled instantly, but rather after little less than one second*. Then you have a slow operation in your function. The function in your code snippet does not look like it should take more than a few milliseconds to finish. So it should look pretty instantaneous to a human eye.

Comment: The constructor of `UploadWorker` might do something that takes time, and will stall the GUI thread as the constructor runs before the call to `moveToThread`. If that's the case, you could move that code to an `init` function which runs in the worker thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're in a slot called from the GUI thread, the GUI thread cannot do other things. Like go back to the event loop or redraw UI.

You can call work around this by calling [`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents), but the Right Thing To Do™ is to keep your slots focused on one simple task and return from them quickly.

Comment: I cannot make it any simpler than start a new Thread, this includes preparation of arguments passed to it. But thank you for your answer, it explains a lot

Comment: Unless you break in with a debugger, the button should be set to disabled as soon as you leave the slot.

Comment: @TomášNavara: If you need to disable the button before starting the thread, e.g. if creating `UploadWorker` obejct takes so long that the button disabling is visibly delayed, then let the slot disable the button and then call another slot via `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` or a single-shot `QTimer` that then creates and starts thread and worker.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this approach? Slots are executed in the order they are connected. So,

```
connect(theOnlyButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {theOnlyButton->setEnabled(false); }); // disable the button first
connect(theOnlyButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(buttonClicked());
```